# Generating Random Java Code

Tags: java, code-generation

I am currently working on a project that involves bytecode transformations, and I'm looking to create an integration test to ensure the robustness of "My Tool". The simplified pipeline for "My Tool" is as follows:

Java Code ➡️ Bytecode ➡️ "My Tool" ➡️ Bytecode

The goal of this integration test is to:

1. Generate random, but valid Java code (that can be compiled successfully).
2. Compile that code
3. Run "My Tool"
4. Verify that no errors occur during the process.

The primary objective here is to confirm that "My Tool" can effectively handle all bytecode instructions and work with a wide range of code samples. However, I'm struggling to find a tool for generating random Java code.
While I could manually create numerous code snippets, this would be an extremely tedious process. So, my question is: Are there any libraries, plugins, or tools available that can assist in generating random Java code snippets?

Comment: Frame challenge: Since in step 1, it is a good idea to then save all the generated examples to get your test library, and have consistent test cases, why not look for an already existing corpus of code that is used for compiler testing? I couldn't find something quickly, otherwise I would give you a link directly. But such a corpus has to exist for sure somewhere.

Comment: @kutschkem I'll definitely try to find some already existing test cases, thank you! At least they can solve the problem in the near future. However, I'm afraid they can be rather large (but I haven't check yet).